# webpackでjQueryをすべてのjsファイル内で使いたい

Tags: jquery, webpack

webpack+scss+jQuery環境を作ろうとしています。
webpack+scssまではできたのですが、jQuery環境がうまくいきません。
index.js内でもutility.js内でも `$` が使えるようにしたいです。

[webpackでjqueryを使用、しかし「$ is not defined」のエラー - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/215905)

こちらを参考にして `plugins:` を記載したのですが、`webpack --watch` の時点でエラーが出てしまいました。

**ディレクトリ構造**

[image: ディレクトリ構造]

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    // メインとなるJavaScriptファイル（エントリーポイント）
    entry: "./js/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    // ファイルの出力設定
    output: {
        //  出力ファイルのディレクトリ名
        path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
        // 出力ファイル名
        filename: "bundle.js"
        // hash値自動付与 変更時はwebpack再起動
        // filename: "bundle_[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                use: [
                    // linkタグに出力する機能
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                use: [
                    // linkタグに出力する機能
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            //相対パス利用する
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                    "sass-loader",
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
        }),
    ],
};
```

**index.js**

```
import '../scss/test.scss';
import * as util from './utility.js'
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.getElementById("js_open").addEventListener("click", util.modalOpen, false);
$("#js_open").on("click", util.changeBig);
```

**utility.js**

```
export function modalOpen() {
    console.log("hello");
}

export function changeBig() {
    $("#js_open").css("width", "40px");
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ReferenceError: webpack is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/www/webpack_test/webpack.config.js:42:13)
    at Module._compile (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/www/webpack_test/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build: `webpack --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1):

webpack.config.jsの一番最初に

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
```

を追加したところ解決しました。